# Webpack Entries and Issues with New dependOn Syntax

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack v5.0.0 beta in my web application, and I'm running into some issues using the new `dependOn` option in the entry section.

I have 2 applications, in separate repos, that I combine in my web app. For simplicity, I'll call them **appA** and **appB**.

Each app has its own repo and its own webpack config. I bundle **appB** and import those bundle files as a dependency of **appA**.

The issue is that since **appB** has multiple entries, there was a lot of duplicate code in the bundle files. I started using the new dependOn syntax which seemed like a great fix, except that now when I try to import **appB** in **appA** I get the following error:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: loadAppB is not a constructor`

When debugging this, in the dev tools, somehow the variable `loadAppB` is assigned to the integer `1`.

Here is how I load **appB** as a dependency inside of **appA**:

```
import( /* webpackChunkName: "AppB" */ "../lib/appB" ).then( module => {
    const loadAppB = module.default;
    window.appB = new loadAppB();
```

Here is the webpack config for **appB**:

```
const path = require("path");
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    AppB: { import: "./src/AppB.js", dependOn: "Class"},
    Class: "./src/Class.js",
    Subclass: { import: "./src/Subclass.js", dependOn: "Class" },
  },

  output: {
    filename: "[name].js",
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
    libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
  },

  mode: "production",

  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
  },

  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
  ],
};
```

What's interesting is that if I modify the entry in appB's webpack config to this:

```
entry: {
    AppB: "./src/AppB.js",
    Class: "./src/Class.js",
    Subclass: { import: "./src/Subclass.js", dependOn: "Class" },
  },
```

instead of this (the original):

```
entry: {
    AppB: { import: "./src/AppB.js", dependOn: "Class"},
    Class: "./src/Class.js",
    Subclass: { import: "./src/Subclass.js", dependOn: "Class" },
  },
```

By removing the `dependOn` option in the entry for **appB** I'm able to successfully load **appB** inside of **appA**.

Even though this works, the **appB** entry file uses the `Class` export, so the code for the `Class` file is duplicated (it appears in the appB bundle as well as its own output bundle)

Has anyone run into something similar or knows why this might be happening?

I'll also include the webpack config for **appA**, in case it helps.

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app: "./js/app.js"
  },

  output: {
    filename: "[name].bundle.js",
    chunkFilename: "[name].bundle.js",
    publicPath: 'build/',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "build"),
  },

  optimization: {
    minimize: false,
    concatenateModules: false,
  },

  mode: "production",
  plugins: [
    new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
    new webpack.SourceMapDevToolPlugin()
  ],

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve('jquery'),
        use: [{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: 'jQuery'
        },{
          loader: 'expose-loader',
          options: '$'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },
};
```

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm running into this exact problem!